# Why was wikification allegedly due to ten owner edits triggered by my non-owner edit?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, revisions-list

After I made [the 14th revision to a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/127704/14) it was converted to community wiki with this message in the revision log:

> [made Community Wiki by [George Edison](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142114/george-edison) editing at least 10 times]

I am not George Edison. He had already edited the post ten times, but it wasn't wikied until I touched it.

A minor bug, perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikification actually happens on N+1 edits - George did indeed edit his post 10 times, but we didn't convert it until the next edit.

Think of it as holding on to the possibility of precious future reps for a little bit longer.