# Why didn't this answer get converted to Community Wiki?

Tags: support, bug, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was wikification allegedly due to ten owner edits triggered by my non-owner edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127778/why-was-wikification-allegedly-due-to-ten-owner-edits-triggered-by-my-non-owner)

Looking at [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/1672/69) and more importantly its [revision history](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/1672/revisions), it can be seen that the original poster has made ten consecutive revisions (ie revisions 2-11). According to the [Community Wiki FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), this should have auto-magically converted the post to Community Wiki.

Why didn't this occur?  Is it something special about this question or have the requirements changed and the FAQ just not been updated?

Comment: Although it seems like the FAQ might be wrong now, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127796/) explains things.

Comment: There was a similar case reported a couple of days ago where the post was only made CW with the next edit after the tenth by the OP. Maybe it needs an action to trigger the CW checker.

Comment: @DanielFischer Tut I'd actually read that question a couple of days back and it didn't register as the same issue.  Thanks :D